# Karma test failing for AngularFireAuth

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angularfire2

I've created test cases using jasmine/karma for my Angular2 web app using AngularFire2 and I'm getting a weird error that I haven't been able to debug.  When I run my test (checking that the app components exists) I get the error

`Failed: app.auth is not a function
at new AngularFireAuth (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/path/to/project/node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.js:11:1)`

Looking into the AngularFire2 files themselves it looks like it's trying to assign a new authentication system to the current app it's creating, but this same code works fine for the other Angular2 project I'm working on.  The version for AngularFire2 is 4.0.0 and Firebase is 4.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with an automatically created effects test and solved creating a stub:

```
const AngularFireMocks = {
    auth: Observable.of({ uid: 'ABC123' })
};
```

and in my test providers I put:

```
{ provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: AngularFireMocks },
```

Complete code (is an effect test):

```
import {TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {provideMockActions} from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

import {AuthEffects} from './auth.effects';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';

const AngularFireMocks = {
    auth: of({ uid: 'ABC123' })
};

describe('AuthEffects', () => {
    let actions$: Observable<any>;
    let effects: AuthEffects;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            providers: [
                AuthEffects,
                { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: AngularFireMocks },
                provideMockActions(() => actions$)
            ]
        });

        effects = TestBed.get(AuthEffects);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(effects).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved by removing "FirebaseApp" from Providers list in the app.module.ts file